# How to Dynamical change the input features for Gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am Trying to implement gradient descent with different input features  , But I want to do it dynamically which is not happening.

Suppose when my input feature in 2 my dataset looks like this.

```
x0 x1 x2 Y
 1 2  3  4
 1 5  6  7
 1 8  9  10
```

then I perform my gradient descent

```
def gradientDescent(x, y, theta, alpha, m, numIterations):
xTrans = x.T
for i in range(0, numIterations):
    hypothesis = np.dot(x, theta)
    loss = hypothesis - y
    cost = np.sum(loss ** 2) / (2 * m)
    print("Iteration %d | Cost: %f" % (i, cost))
    # avg gradient per example
    gradient = np.dot(xTrans, loss) / m
    # update
    theta = theta - alpha * gradient
return theta
```

where theta is weights , alpha is learning rate , m = length of the dataset at that time, numIteration is basically the number of time the gradient descent will run.

once the gradient descent is done , the my shape of input features change

```
X0 X1 X2 X3  Y
1  2  3  4   5
1  6  7  8   9
1 10 11 12   13
```

then again it will calculate the gradient descent with the above function all with that it should iteratively plot the graph with respect to numIterations and cost

I am getting stuck in creating a dynamic structure where it should take the number of features dynamically and calculate the gradient descent

Manually I am able to do it but when it's more than 6 or 7 features it becomes really difficult to run it atmost number of times.

Comment: _How exactly_ are you getting stuck? What exactly happens when the number of features becomes 7? I don't see why your function would care about the shape of `x`: you pass `x` of shape, say, `(3, 4)`, as in your example, and `theta` of the appropriate shape too - that should work fine

Comment: The X shape is change and passed it on to the main gradient descent function to take care of dot product. Basically for x is x = df.iloc[: , :-1],x.shape, then weights shape is changed to do dot product , so the weight shape goes in like this n3 = np.array(weights(len(df.columns)-1))
nn3=n3.reshape(-1,1)
nn3.shape

Comment: so I am doing it in hyperparameter way so when N=1 ,my data has 3 columns one x0 column which is always 1 , one is x1 column, one is Y column, when I move to next hyper parameter means when N=2 my dataset changes to 4 columns ,one is 'x0' whose value is always 1 and the other columns are x1,x2,Y and like wise it goes on to certain hyperparameters